# send amound to card reader

Tags: node.js, payment, com-port, cardreader

in my case,
I want to send price information to my credit card reader to receive payment.

I want to enter the price information in the program I wrote and send the price information to my POS device via the USB comport connection. I created a code using node.js for this, but while it shows that it is working in the terminal, payment information does not come to the POS device.
ingenico move3500

```
const SerialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort;

const COM_PORT = 'COM4';  
const BAUD_RATE = 115200;   

const sendPriceToPos = (price) => {
  const port = new SerialPort({path:COM_PORT,  baudRate: BAUD_RATE }, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('Connection Error:', err.message);
    }

    console.log(`POS connected: ${COM_PORT}`);
    
    
    const command = `PRICE`;
    port.write(command, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('ERROR:', err.message);
    
    }
      console.log(`Amound İnfo Sended: ${price}`);

      
      port.close((err) => {
        if (err) {
          return console.error('Connection Shut Down Error:', err.message);
        }
        console.log('Connection shut down sucssesfuly.');
      });
    });
  });
};

sendPriceToPos( 500);
```

Comment: Where does your code send the `price` variable to the serial connection? I only see it being used in a `console.log()` call.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the commands should be terminated with something, e.g. a newline. You should refer to the programming manual for the terminal for actual instructions (I can't easily find it online).

Answer (score 1):

Ugur,  I am not able to give you any help with that specific device, but I can tell you a little bit about how we do this.
I work for a company named USIO and we are a payment processor.
We have smart terminals that connect directly to the internet via Wifi, Ethernet, or 4G rather than a USB cable.
To activate them you just make an API call to our webservice with the amount you want to charge and the terminal lights up to take that amount.
They can do swipe, chip, and contactless including Apple Pay and Google Pay.
They are Android based terminals and are very inexpensive.
If you would like to know more I would be happy to introduce you to our head of development who can demo it for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree, the smart terminals are so much easier to work with and can reduce PCI scope.
I looked up their offerings and you can find them here: https://usio.com/terminals